# Accidental SVN check-in

Tags: visual-studio, svn, tortoisesvn

OK, this is a real-life scenario and I don't want to take risk, so I'm asking.

I and Bob are working on a .NET project (VS2010) which is under SVN. Everything was running fine till today. And then Bob made a mistake when committing. Here's a brief history of commits:

Rev. 158    -    Me    -    All fine - I checked-in some work

Rev. 159    -    Bob   -    All fine - Bob checked-in some work

Rev. 160    -    Bob   -    Committed some blunders

I had continue further work after committing Rev. 158 and now my working copy contains lots of work that needs to be checked in. How can I ask SVN (I have Tortoise) to simply purge Rev. 160 and go back to Rev. 159 state? I read a few other posts and they suggest using SVN History and clicking on last good commit and choosing "Revert to this revision" command from context menu, but if I do that, it asks me if I want to revert my WORKING COPY to Rev. 159, which means I'll lose all my changes. I just want the server-side to simply undo Rev. 160 without affecting my working copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reverting to a previous revision is called a *reverse merge* in Subversion.

From the command line, you can do this:

```
$ svn merge -c -160 .
```

Note the minus sign in front of the revision. This says to remove the changes introduced with Revision 160. You can do this even after other revisions have been checked in. However, the longer you want, the more likely there could be *merge conflicts*.

You can also do a [reverse merge](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-howto-rollback.html) in Tortoise. This can be done via the log (right click on a revision and select *revert*), or via the Merge dialog box (select the *reverse merge* checkbox).

---

### Use AnkhSVN instead of TortoiseSVN

Since you're doing .NET development, I assume you're using VisualStudio. If you are, use [AnkhSVN](https://ankhsvn.open.collab.net) instead of TortoiseSVN. AnkhSVN integrates inside of Visual Studio, and knows what VisualStudio cruft not to add into the repository (unlike TortoiseSVN).

Comment: A couple of notes which may or may not help: I'm not sure 'merge -c' actually "makes the change" at the server, however. I believe the change would still have to be committed. Also, TortoiseSvn can easily be configured to ignore "Visual Studio cruft" by adding them to the global ignore pattern in Settings. The VS/.NET stuff I have globally ignored is 'obj \*.suo debug \*.user \*.vshost.\*'

Comment: The `merge -c -%REV%` makes the change at the server when you commit the change. It doesn't remove the bad revision. In Subversion, once you commit, that revision is there forever (unless you dump/filter/load). However, `merge -c -%REV%` undoes whatever changes were in revision `%REV%`.

Comment: TortoiseSVN can be used (as well as the command line client). However, AnkhSVN is already configured to ignore VisualStudio cruft. Plus, it's integrated in VisualStudio, so there's one less management window needed. You don't have to flip back and forth between two programs. AnkhSVN will warn you about files that aren't added to the repo, but are needed as part of the build.

Comment: If the guy is already using TortoiseSVN, then I guess that its fair to mention VisualSVN (plug-in for Visual Studio) as well.

Comment: @bahrep Sure. Both AnkhSVN and VisualSVN are VisualStudio plugins. AnkhSVN is licensed under the Apache Open Source License. VisualSVN has a [proprietary license](http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/purchase/) and costs $79 per license for most developers. (Microsoft MVPs, Open Source projects are some exceptions). If you use VisualSVN, please use it under the correct license and pay for it if you required by the license.